# Чи це і справді людина, ливар, що відливає металеві вироби?

Tags: значення-слів

Що саме означає слово ***ливарі*** в  поезії Василя Стуса? Невже це  ***[ливар](http://sum.in.ua/s/lyvar)***, робітник, який відливає металеві вироби?

Загусає далеч вечорова,
граціозні **ливарі** мовчать.
Спить долина, зморена діброва,
а над ставом лебеді ячать.
А над полем висипали зорі.
А над небом зупинився Бог.
А над Богом править серце хоре,
окрутенств шукаючи на двох.
Спить діброва. Спить земля велика,
всесвіт спить. Мовчання — як зоря,
і знесла правицю яснолика
Доля, не віщуючи добра.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [Тлумачному словнику Василя Стуса](https://ukrreferat.com/chapters_book/literatura-ukrainska/slovnik-vstusa-tlumachnij-slovnik.html) ливарі в наведеній поезії пояснюються просто:

> ЛивAр, -я?, ч. Робітник, який відливає металеві вироби. Загусає далеч вечорова,/ граціозні ливарі мовчать.

Але насмілюся припустити, що мова йде про пам'ятник ливарям, що їх доволі велика кількість стоїть в Запорізькій, Дніпровській, Донецькій областях. Один із них, у Кам'янці, що на Дніпровщині, навіть можна назвати граціозним.